# justify the paragraph in terms & condition checkbox using html css

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

How can Ijustify the paragraph in terms & condition with checkbox using css. I can't find the simple way on how to justify it. I'm new in HTML/CSS, and I'm still having a hard time figuring it out.

```css
input {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

label {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  text-align: justify;
}

p {
  margin-top: 2em;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="agree" />
  <label for="agree">
                        I declare that I have been provided with documents by Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint est adipisci, earum ratione tempora rerum?
                    </label>
</p><br>
<p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint est adipisci, earum ratione tempora rerum?</p>
```

[image]

I attached the photo that I wanted to get. Thank you.

Comment: Please format your question and also use the code-snippet feature so that we can see the result live.

Comment: i didn't quite get what you are wanting to do. do you want your checkmark at the right bottom side of the text ?

Comment: Do those elements have a parent element? Any siblings?

Comment: Hi all, I just want to indent all the paragraph so all of them are justified (as shown in the photo).

Comment: @Esko, I think someone already formatted my question :). Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've restructured the HTML structure and provided styles according to the design image.
Hope it will help you.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  place-items: flex-start baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  gap: 1em;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="agree" />
  <label for="agree">
    <p> I declare that I have been provided with documents by Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint est adipisci, earum ratione tempora rerum?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint est adipisci, earum ratione tempora rerum?</p>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check the given design image and code

Comment: @JaswinderKaur Yup, edited my answer according to given design image.

Comment: I had never encountered `text-justify` before now; every day remains a school day :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This is what I really wanted to do. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your last `p` tag to align with the `label` tag then you can add inline CSS `margin-left` or add class to the last `p` tag and apply margin-left.

```css
input {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

label {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  text-align: justify;
}

p {
  margin-top: 2em;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="agree" />
  <label for="agree">
                        I declare that I have been provided with documents by Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint est adipisci, earum ratione tempora rerum?
                    </label>
</p><br>
<p>
  <p style="margin-left: 2.5rem;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint est adipisci, earum ratione tempora rerum?</p>
```

```css
input {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

label {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  text-align: justify;
}

p {
  margin-top: 2em;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.terms-condition {
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="agree" />
  <label for="agree">
                        I declare that I have been provided with documents by Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint est adipisci, earum ratione tempora rerum?
                    </label>
</p><br>
<p>
  <p class="terms-condition">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint est adipisci, earum ratione tempora rerum?</p>
```